# magento 1 - How to addClass without JS to the dropdown filter in Admin custom grid

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, custom-admin-grid

**I want to add class to the magento admin custom grid filter dropdown.**

I have dropdown in one filter column and I dont want to use JS to reduce client side load.

Is there anyway to add class while preparing column to the grid.php?

```
$this->addColumn('mfg', array(
   'header' => Mage::helper('manufacturer')->__('Manufacturer'),
   'index' => 'mfg_id',
   'filter_index' => 'SFOIA.mfg_id',
   'type' => 'options',
   'options' => $this->getManufacturersWithExtraOption(),
   'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_manufacturerCallback'),
));
```

I dont want add class to the column - Need class to the filter dropdown only. just in to its  html

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

this is good way to add class in your custom column

```
$this->addColumn('mfg', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('manufacturer')->__('Manufacturer'),
            'index' => 'mfg_id',
            'filter_index' => 'SFOIA.mfg_id',
            'type' => 'options',
            'options' => $this->getManufacturersWithExtraOption(),
            'filter_condition_callback' => array($this, '_manufacturerCallback'),
            'column_css_class' => 'your_class'
        ));
```

`column_css_class` allows you to add a class to the columns that hold values.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it adds class to the `<td>` tag. I want to add class to the filter   `<select>` tag.